# How to use SQL with Power BI in Direct Query Mode for Impala data sources?

Tags: hadoop, powerbi, impala

When using direct query mode, I see options to edit query using the GUI, but it is limited.

I see an advanced editor, but that is not SQL; it seems to be Power BI specific syntax.

I am using Impala data source. The query I am trying to use is like this:

```
SELECT *FROM database1.table1
WHERE (col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NULL)
OR    (col1 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NULL)
```

The `OR` seems to be the challenge.

Is there a way for me to use my SQL directly in Power BI for Impala data sources with direct query mode? If not, I may have to create a table in Impala that has exactly what I need to be able to query without the `OR` statements thru Power BI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed this option is not available using Impala data sources.
Instead of using Impala data source, you can select the ODBC data source then select HDFS. You will then get the advanced options including ability to use SQL on import. Note I have heard reports that complex SQL can cause Power BI to crash; therefore, creating tables using complex SQL outside Power BI , then pointing Power BI to that table may still be a viable option.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nvEB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/micVg.png)

Comment: Note: i have HDFS listed in the description , this is because we named our ODBC connection HDFC, you would use the ODBC connection name you gave to  your Impala ODBC connection.